# What is the difference between Turtle and Tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, python-turtle

I may sound dumb but seriously what is the difference between Turtle and Tkinter? They both use graphics and other stuff

Comment: `turtle` is a package built on top of `tkinter`. I could argue that it should only be used to learn how procedural programming works but that's just my opinion. Look at some basic tutorials for both `turtle` and `tkinter` and decide which is best for your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turtle is used mainly to draw, using lines and shapes, while Tkinter is used to make GUI : graphical user interfaces. Meaning you import text, buttons, frames, and so on

Comment: Don't forget that you have `tkinter.Canvas` which is just like a `turtle` screen.

Comment: Yeah, basically, tkinter is a way more advanced library, made for designing GUIs and that includes a turtle-like

Answer (score 0):

While `tkinter` is mainly used for GUI (Buttons, Widgets and Text), `turtle` is mainly used for UI (Animations and Games). Also `turtle` was designed as a way for kids to learn how to code easily.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter is a GUI module built in to the *Python Standard library*. One of the **widgets** that you can use is the `Canvas`. Try running this code below.

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

canvas_width = 800
canvas_height = 400
w = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height,)
w.pack()

y = int(canvas_height / 2)
w.create_line(0, y, canvas_width, y, fill="#000000")


mainloop()
```

You'll notice that it creates a canvas and that it draws a black line on it. Well, `turtle` is based around this canvas object and draws stuff for you when, for example, you get the turtle to move. They are all based around the same thing: Tkinter Canvases.

I hope that I could be of assistance.